# Toolbar does not hide while scrolling Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, material-components-android

I want the toolbar to hide completely when I scroll the recycler view up and become visible when I scroll down. but the toolbar does not hide when I scroll the recycler view, the toolbar just remains fixed.

Here is my code:

The main_actionbar.xml file contains the toolbar and I used it in the activity_main.xml with .<Include

The activity_main.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/veryLightGrey"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/main_actionbar" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/notes_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
        android:background="@color/veryLightGrey"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />
   

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The main_actionbar.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/dusty_grey">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainTobar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/action_barName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="note"
    />


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/handling-scrolls-with-coordinatorlayout#code-samples

refer this

Comment: Update (now works):  so the problem was I was using <include> to use the action bar in the activity_main.xml, it started working after I pasted the action bar code directly in the activity_main.xml and removed margin-top attribute from the recycler view.  Pls, I'm curious to why i can't put the action bar code separately and use it with <include> in activity_main.xml. @EndUser

Comment: it's not the include tag it's because you are adding one more coordinator layout as a parent in your include layout

Comment: @EndUser yes exactly, thank you very much. Is it that generally reusable layout files that will be used with  <include> shouldn't have layouts like (Linear layout, Coordinator layouts etc) ?

Comment: No it's not the general case but for what you wanted to achieve.

Comment: ooh okay, Thanks alot i really appreciate your reply.